# How can I remove specific nodes from a scenekit scene?

Tags: swift, nodes, scenekit

I use following code, it will check the touch point and it will add the object if the point is empty or delete the object.

```
@objc func didTap(withGestureRecognizer recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        let tapLocation = recognizer.location(in: sceneView)
        let hitTestResults = sceneView.hitTest(tapLocation)

        guard let node = hitTestResults.first?.node else {

            let hitTestResultsWithFeaturePoints = sceneView.hitTest(tapLocation, types: .featurePoint)

            if let hitTestResultWithFeaturePoints = hitTestResultsWithFeaturePoints.first {

                let translation = hitTestResultWithFeaturePoints.worldTransform.translation

                guard let carScene = SCNScene(named: "car.dae") else { return }
                let carNode = SCNNode()
                let carSceneChildNodes = carScene.rootNode.childNodes
                for childNode in carSceneChildNodes {
                    carNode.addChildNode(childNode)
                }
                carNode.position = SCNVector3(translation.x, translation.y, translation.z)
                carNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
                sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(carNode)
            }
            return

        }
    node.removeFromParentNode()
}
```

But my object is create by DAE file, it include lot of childNodes.
if i use `node.removeFromParentNode()` it will only remove one node

if i use following code it will remove all of object on the screen.

```
sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (existingNode, _) in
        existingNode.removeFromParentNode()
    }
```

How can I remove specific nodes from a scenekit scene?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should name your nodes then you can use the name to filter them out.

```
sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNodes.filter({ $0.name == "yourName" }).forEach({ $0.removeFromParentNode() })
```

Comment: thanks for response, but it doesn't work and show "Extra argument 'withName' in call" error message.

Comment: Right sorry i confused `SpriteKit` with `SceneKit`. Check edited answer.

Comment: i try to use `sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNodes.filter({ $0.name == "car.dae" }).forEach({ $0.removeFromParentNode() })` , but it doesn't work. should i change didTap func?

Comment: Well that wouldn't work because `car.dae` is an `SCNScene` not a node, so try declaring `carScene` outside the didTap func so you can filter it's childNodes.

Comment: i sorry i don't have any idea about declaring carScene outside the didTap func.how should i do?

Comment: `var carScene: SCNScene?` outside of the didTap but in the class scope, then init it in `viewDidLoad` `carScene = SCNScene(named: "car.dae")` and change this line `guard let carScene = SCNScene(named: "car.dae") else { return }` to this `guard carScene != nil else { return }`

Comment: i still can not remove it. the car.dae file is come from this github https://github.com/appcoda/ARKit3DDemo.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
func childNode(withName name: String, 
   recursively: Bool) -> SCNNode?
```

Head over to docs, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407951-childnode